# Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? I am having problems debugging

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game for school project where you just shoot enemies on the other side of the screen. And I am having trouble debugging. I am using python and pygame. The errors come from the image and the player_image, i think that the main problem is something with displaying the background as that is what I was trying to do Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(image)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width//2, screen_height//2))


        def update(self):
            self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        def create_bullet(self):
            return Bullet(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0].pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1])


class Bullet (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().def__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,10))
        self.image.fill((255,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (pos_x,pos_y))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 5

# general setup
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# game screen
screen_width = 1920
screen_height = 1080
screen = pygame .display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
background = pygame.image.load("BackGround.png")

# player
player = pygame.image.load("spriteshd00.png")
player = Player(player_image)
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(player)

bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

# caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Wild-West Shooter")



# makes game quit
while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame:quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    bullet_group.add(player.create_bullet())

        while True:
            # handel events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame: quit()
                    sys.exit()

            # update the game states and positions of objects
            player_group.update()

            # draw the background
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

            # draw objects
            player_group.draw(screen)

            # update display
            pygame.display.flip()

            clock.tick(120)


    #drawing
        pygame.display.flip()
        player_group.draw(screen)
        bullet_group.draw(screen)
        player_group.update()
        bullet.group.update()
        screen.blit(background,(0,0))
        clock.tick(120)





if __name__ == "__main__" :
        theApp = App()
        theApp.on_execute()
```

Comment: What is the error message? Please show the error trace.

Comment: What *exactly* happened when you tried to run the code, and how *exactly* is that different from what is supposed to happen? If you got an error message, copy and paste it into the question, formatted as code. If something visually appeared wrong, include screenshots and diagrams as appropriate. We can only help you solve problems that we actually know about.

Comment: `player = pygame.image.load("spriteshd00.png")` -> `player_image = pygame.image.load("spriteshd00.png")`

Comment: line 40, in <module>
    player = Player(player_image)
NameError: name 'player_image' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image` must be an argument of the constructor of `Player`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(image)
        self.image = image
        
        # [...]
```

The name of the _Surface is `player_image`:

<s>`player = pygame.image.load("spriteshd00.png")`</s>

```py
player_image = pygame.image.load("spriteshd00.png")
player = Player(player_image)
```

There is another typo in the constructor of `Bullets`

<s>`super().def__init__()`</s>

```py
super().__init__()
```

Furthermore there are some structural and [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) issues. Complete and working code:

```py
import pygame, sys

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width//2, screen_height//2))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    def create_bullet(self):
        return Bullet(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())

class Bullet (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,10))
        self.image.fill((255,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (pos_x,pos_y))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 5

# general setup
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# game screen
screen_width = 1920
screen_height = 1080
screen = pygame .display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
background = pygame.image.load("BackGround.png")

# player
player_image = pygame.image.load("spriteshd00.png")
player = Player(player_image)
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(player)

bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

# caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Wild-West Shooter")

# makes game quit
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame:quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet_group.add(player.create_bullet())

    player_group.update()
    bullet_group.update()

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    player_group.draw(screen)
    bullet_group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```